# Can style be applied on nested React Native components by passing it as prop to the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have a layout like this:

```
<Container>
    <Name> 
        {name}
    </Name>
    <City>
        {city}
    </City>
</Container>
```

and here the expected output is name and city to be aligned to the left. I want another component in which those 2 components will be centrally aligned. I know that I can use `textAlign='center'` directly on Name and City, but what I want is to set that property in the parent Container, because if I had 10 nested elements and all of them should be centrally aligned, I would prefer not to write the same style property for all components.

Ideally I would have something like:

```
<Container textAlignChildren='center'>
   ...
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the children using [`React.Children.map`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children), returning a clone of each child using [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).  This method will create a new element with the props passed as the second argument merged.

```
class Container extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.renderChildren = this.renderChildren.bind(this);
    }

    renderChildren() {
        const { children, textAlignChildren } = this.props;

        // Iterate over children and return clones
        return React.Children.map(children, child => {
            //return cloned child with merged style
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                style: { textAlign: textAlignChildren }
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderChildren}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You will call this as follows

```
<Container textAlignChildren="center">
   <Child />
   <Child />
   <Child />
</Container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I want to achieve is to avoid passing style to each element. I want just to pass the style prop to the `Container` and it will implicitly pass it to all its children.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for @giliev

Answer (score 0):

You should use Flexbox to style your user interface in React Native.

If you want to display a series of components, one after the other, "on each line" (e.g with a Text), centralized vertically, you should set the **alignItems** property of the parent container to have value **'center'**.

Example

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Some Child</Text>
  <Text>Some Child</Text>
  <Text>Some Child</Text>
  <Text>Some Child</Text>
</View>
```

Note: by default, the main axis in React Native is going vertically down the screen, so `flexDirection` is `'column'` unless specified to be a different value. I highly recommend you take a look at [this reference for Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) for React Native is also helpful.